# How can I delete member of a collection without fetching it from a one-to-many association using hibernate criteria or hql?

Tags: associations, hql, criteria, one-to-many, hibernate-onetomany

I have a one-to-many association from Institution -> Course where
 **an institution can handle multiple courses**. For **this use case** consider **a course can only belong to one institution**.

```
@Entity 
Institution {
@Id
long id;
@JoinTable(name = "INSTITUTION_COURSES", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "INSTITUTION_ID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "COURSE_ID"))
Set<Course> coursesOffered;
}

@Entity
Course{
@Id
long id;
@Column
String name;
}
```

**And their map is stored in seperate table**

How can I delete a course using HQL or Hibernate criteria without fetching the Institution object and the associated collection such that the corresponding rows in the mapping table are also removed.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing something like this inside a transactional context? ...

```
Institution institution = institutionDAO.findById(institutionId, false);
institution.getCourses().remove(course);

institution = institutionDAO.mergeState(institution);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But your implementation fetches institution and the courses and then  removes the course. I am looking for a criteria or hql query that can delete a course and the associated mapping information without fetching institution and all its courses.

Comment: This is a good question and I would also like to know how to do this. Recently I had to use a NativeQuery to do this because I could not find a way with Criteria API. Can you improve your question to include the mapping? Also please rename the question to indicate that you wish to delete a member of a collection without fetching it.

Comment: Please find the updated question and description. The mapping information is stored in a separate table institution_courses. So my question is how can i delete a course so that the associated mapping information is also deleted.